# Como ordenar uma lista de dicionário de forma alfabética e gerar novos dicionários com condição if com Python?

Tags: python

Boa noite,

Estou com um exercício de Python que me travou, é o seguinte:

*Leia e armazene em um dicionário o nome, a idade e o número do telefone de seus contatos, sendo que a chave deve ser o nome. Ao digitar uma string vazia para o nome, o programa interrompe a leitura e se encerra.
Apresente na tela os dados lidos em ordem alfabética pelo nome dos contatos. Uma possível solução de ordenar alfabeticamente é usar o método sort.
Em seguida, armazene os contatos em outros dois dicionários, utilizando como critério a idade: menores de 18 anos em um e os maiores em outro dicionário, eliminando o original. Apresente na tela os dois dicionários resultantes da separação.*

Eu consegui gerar o dicionário e suas listas de acordo com a entrada e o break do programa caso a primeira entrada do nome seja string vázia.

Porém não consigo imprimir em ordem alfabética o dicionário, visto que se aplico o sort na chave name, ajusta apenas ela e se aplico nas demais bagunça todas as informações.
Também não consegui pensar em uma forma de fazer essa separação dos dicionários, dividindo os contatos que forem maiores que 18 anos em um e os menores em outro dicionário e eliminando o original.

Alguém poderia me dar uma ideia por favor?

Código até o momento:

```
informations = {'name':[], 'age':[], 'cellphone':[]}

for i in range(3):
  name = str(input('Qual o nome do seu contato? '))
  if name == "":
    print('Programa encerrado...')
    break
  age = int(input('Qual a idade do seu contato? '))
  cellphone = int(input('Qual o número de celular do seu contato? '))
  
  informations['name'].append(name)
  informations['name'].sort()
  informations['age'].append(age)
  informations['cellphone'].append(cellphone)

print('')
print(informations)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa! Há um problema no desenho do teu programa pois você não está armazenando nome, idade e telefone em um dicionário e sim, armazenando nomes, idades e telefones não relacionado entre si.

Ou seja, ao invés de:

```py
informations = {'name':[], 'age':[], 'cellphone':[]}
```

Você deveria usar:

```py
informations = []
```

Com cada item da lista fica armazenando as informações do contato:

```py
informations.append({'name': name, 'age':age, 'cellphone':cellphone})
```

Então é possível usar o `sort()` para ordenar a lista:

```py
informations.sort(key=lambda contact: contact["name"])
```

Esta parte depois do "key=" é uma função que o `sort()` usará para recuperar o valor a ser usado na ordenação. E a função *lambda* cuida justamente de retornar o nome do contato e apenas para exemplificar:

```
>>> c = {"name": "José", "age": 10, "cellphone": "9876-5432"}
>>> c = lambda i: i["name"]
>>> a(c)
'José'
```

Este *lambda* é equivalente a um

```py
def c(i):
    return i["name"]
```

Só que mais simples.

Ah, e para maiores detalhes consulte o [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) do Python.

E quanto a separar em dois dicionários, há diversas maneiras mas como você faria se se fossem fichas de papel? Você olharia cadastro por cadastro e faria duas pilhas com quem é maior, ou não de 18 anos:

```py
greater_than_18, lesser_than_18 = [], []

for contact in information:
    if contact["age"] > 18:
        greater_than_18.append(...)
    else:
        lesser_than_18.append(...)
```

È possível fazer isto de várias formas mas este é o jeito mais simples.

Comment: Nossa que show Giovanni, agora me clareou muito nessa questão, muito obrigado pelo auxílio